# AutoHotKey Basic Script to exit a game

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a simple script to exit "Path of Exile" with F1.
To do that I have to click ESC in the game and then Mouse Click in position 964,440.
I have tried few ways to do that but without luck.

Info:

```
Path of Exile ahk_class Direct3DWindowClass
On Screen:              964, 440
In Active Window:       964, 440
```

Comment: Can you add what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way...

```
#ifWinActive, ahk_class Direct3DWindowClass
    F1::
        Send, {Esc}
        Sleep, 500
        Click, 964, 440
    Return
#ifWinActive
```

This will ONLY work when your program is active. When your program is active the <kbd>F1</kbd> key will cause the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to be pressed and after 400 ms, it will click on your specific X/Y coordinates. When your program is not running the <kbd>F1</kbd> key will act as normal.

Comment: @CoolPops, could you please "Accept" my answer in the system, thank you!

Comment: Since the answer was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!